# Sitewide 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect

I have just completed a website remodel. The website will be hosted on the same domain, however the page names are going to change. For example `www.example.com/one_two.html` will be changed to `www.example.com/one_dos.html`. I intend on using a 301 redirect in order to not lose SEO ranking. I was can anyone tell me how to do this for the entire site?

Comment: What web server (and indeed scripting language) is in use?

Comment: what is your current site architecture?

Comment: I am uploading to a ftp site also

Answer (score 0):

Create a relation between old and new URL and then create regular expression based on them. Then add the redirection code in the .htaccess file..

This link may help you http://webtips.in/301-redirect-using-htaccess